# Sum of column if the value in that column's cell is the maximum in the row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice

I have a spreadsheet with eight columns and many rows. Each column represents a price with a vendor. Each row represents a product.

I'd like to add a top row that is the sum of each product at that vendor's price IF that price is the maximum price across all eight vendors.

I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

`=SUMIF(H3:H5000, "=", MAX(H3:O3)))`

I have these two segments, which each solve half of the problem, but don't know how to combine them:

`=IF(H3=MAX(H3:O3), H3, 0)`

`SUM(H3:H5000)`

How do I accomplish this?

---

As requested in comments,  here is a visual representation of what I am trying to do:

[image]

I am looking for the formula that generates the results shown in the first row -- adding up all the green cells, which are the maximum values in each row (permitting duplicates).

Comment: Could you clarify with some visual representation of input and desired output?

Comment: I added an image. Let me know if you need more.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Both libreoffice and Excel 2016. The spreadsheet is shared on two computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a helper column in column `P` with the formula:

```
=MAX(H3:O3)
```

and copy down.
And then in cell `H1`, add the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(H3:H6*($P3:$P6=H3:H6))
```

and copy across.

Comment: This worked for me; I didn't mind adding a helper column. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Bit of a stretch but in `H1` you could add:

```
=SUM(IF(H3:H14=SUBTOTAL(4,OFFSET(INDEX($H3:$O14,1,1),ROW($H3:$O14)-MIN(ROW($H3:$O14)),,,COLUMNS($H3:$O14))),H3:H14,0))
```

Enter through CSE if you don't have Excel O365 and drag to the right.